# socket.io https connect triggering passport.js deserializeUser

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, passport.js

I currently have a working app utilizing passport.js authentication and socket.io for web sockets.  It works fine via the http protocol, but as soon as I tell socket.io to listen to the https server, `deserializeUser()` fires for every connect event and no connection is made, no socket.io middleware is called.

HTTP (works):

```
var server =  http.createServer(app).listen(port) //3000;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

HTTPS (fails):

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(httpsPort)//8443;
//also attempted without any additional options supplied to io.listen()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer, {
  "log level": 3,
  "match origin protocol" : true,
  "transports" : ['websocket']
});
```

The client side:

```
var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
```

Socket.io middleware that should be responding (again, same middleware works when http server is supplied to `io.listen()`):

```
module.exports = function(app, io){
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('base connection');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('disconnect');
  });
});
};
```

Do I have to specify protocol in the client somehow?  I assume the io manager should use the url protocol.  I also assumed passing `"match origin protocol" : true` as an option should use https. Any advice or assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:

The client throws a network error, `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`
[image]